# Vue.js <MyButton @click="click(event)">Click</MyButton> is not working, however, $event works, why?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Please see this minimum example:

I have a minimum custom button called `MyButton` like this

```
<template>
<button @click="click">
  <slot />
</button>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    click(event) {
      this.$emit('click', event)
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Now, I use `<MyButton />` like this

```
<template>
  <div>
    <MyButton @click="click(event)">Click</MyButton>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import MyButton from "./components/MyButton";

export default {
  components: {
    MyButton
  },
  methods: {
    click(event) {
      alert(
        JSON.stringify(event.currentTarget.getBoundingClientRect(), null, 2)
      );
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

This code breaks with following console error

```
[Vue warn]: Property or method "event" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.
[Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'currentTarget' of undefined"
TypeError: Cannot read property 'currentTarget' of undefined
```

However, if I change `@click="click(event)"` to `@click="click($event)"`, now my code works fine as I expected!

Why is this happening?

The [doc](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html) says

> Sometimes we also need to access the original DOM event in an inline statement handler. You can pass it into a method using the special $event variable:

However, as you can see, `<MyButton />` has already emitted the `event` as payload, why would I still use the `$event` version, it's quite confusing for me.

My Codesandbox link

https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-platform-521d8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@click="click"` is actually a shortcut for `@click="click($event)"`, and `$event` is the name of the variable containing the event payload.

It's true for any Vue.js event, for example `@custom-event="myMethod"` is the same as `@custom-event="myMethod($event)"`, where $event is the payload passed by the emitter: `this.$emit('custom-event', payload);`

In most cases, the `@click="click"` is enough for your needs, but in some cases, you may want to pass multiple parameters, and that's where you use `$event`

Example:

`@click="click($event, true, 10)"` can be handled with that kind of function:

```js
click(event, param1, param2) {
    // event is the payload
    // param1 is equal to true
    // param2 is equal to 10
}
```

You can also decide to ignore the payload because you don't need it, and call your function without any parameter: `@click="click()"`

Answer (score 0):

`window.event` is deprecated. Because you still need it in a way in Vue.js, the Vue developing team solved it with introducing `$event`. See [Methods in Inline Handlers](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Methods-in-Inline-Handlers).

See also [MDN `window.event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event):

> You *should* avoid using this property in new code, and should instead use the `Event` passed into the event handler function. This property is not universally supported and even when supported introduces potential fragility to your code.

To understand why `window.event` isn't accessible in the Vue event handler, even if your browser still supports it, you have to understand how the JavaScript event loop and Vue.js works inside. `window.event` is only accessible in the one iteration of the event loop caused by the event itself. But Vue.js doesn't pass the event in that iteration. Instead it will timeout with 0ms and cause it's own iteration. Explaining the why is far too complicated to be of interest.